# Why is there no .tex file created by my script?

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, latex

I tried to run this script (from https://tug.org/tug2019/slides/slides-ziegenhagen-python.pdf, on page 12)

```py
import subprocess, os

with open("sometexfile.tex","w") as file:
  file.write("\\documentclass{article}\n")
  file.write("\\begin{document}\n")
  file.write("Hello Palo Alto!\n")
  file.write("\\end{document}\n")


x = subprocess.call("pdflatex sometexfile.tex")
if x != 0:
  print("Exit-code not 0, please check result!")
else:
  os.system("start sometexfile.pdf")
```

but it gives my the following error :

```
line 39, in <module>
    x = subprocess.call("pdflatex sometexfile.tex")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdflatex sometexfile.tex'
```

Comment: use `run` and not `call`, that's the recommended way. Use `shell=True` and read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, one with `shell=True` and one setted to `False` (noticed that is OS dependent).

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
> the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
> recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

use the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for further information concerning the OSs differences.

Setting `shell=True` carries some [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). It's better to pass a command as list and not as a string

```py
cmd = "pdflatex sometexfile.tex".split()
```

or for more complicated cases use the ad-hoc command [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) from the standard library.

```py
cmd = ["pdflatex", path_tex_file]

cp = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=False)

if cp.returncode != 0:
    print("Exit-code not 0, please check result!")
```

---

Notice that the auxiliary files (aux, toc, ...)could be written in the other directory (depending where you run the code in your environment), check the options for `pdflatex --help`. An example could be

```py
# tell pdflatex to write the output at a specific directory
path_dir = # your path
cmd = ["pdflatex", "-output-directory", path_dir, path_tex_file]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

`os.system("pdflatex sometexfile.tex")`

instead of

`subprocess.call("pdflatex sometexfile.tex")`.

Comment: Don't do that, is system dependent. As written in [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): _The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; **using that module is preferable** to using this [`os.system`] function_

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to wrong addressing.
It's better to use

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "sometexfile.tex"
x = subprocess.call(f"pdflatex {file_path}")
if x != 0:
  print("Exit-code not 0, please check result!")
else:
  os.system(f"start {file_path}")
```

Comment: Why thinking? The OP provides a full minimal example, test it with your answer... and maybe the problem will be still there!